# How to install nvm in docker?

Tags: node.js, docker, nvm

I am in the process of building a new Docker image and I'm looking to get NVM installed so I can manage nodejs.

Reading the docs on how to install NVM they mention that you need to source your .bashrc file in order to start using NVM.

I've tried to set this up in a Dockerfile, but so far building fails with the error:

"bash: nvm: command not found"

Here are the relevant lines from my Dockerfile:

```
ADD files/nvm_install.sh /root/
RUN chmod a+x  /root/nvm_install.sh
RUN bash -c "/root/nvm_install.sh"
RUN bash -l -c "source /root/.bashrc"
RUN cd /root
RUN bash -l -c "nvm install 0.10.31"
```

Here is the output from trying to build:

docker build -t nginx_dock .

```
Step 0 : FROM ubuntu
---> 826544226fdc
Step 1 : MAINTAINER dficociello
---> Using cache
---> da3bc340fbb3
Step 2 : RUN apt-get update
---> Using cache
---> 6b6b611feb4f
Step 3 : RUN apt-get install nginx curl -y
---> Using cache
---> 159eb0b16d23
Step 4 : RUN touch /root/.bashrc
---> Using cache
---> 5e9e8216191b
Step 5 : ADD files/nginx.conf /etc/nginx/
---> Using cache
---> c4a4a11296a2
Step 6 : ADD files/nvm_install.sh /root/
---> Using cache
---> b37cba2a18ca
Step 7 : RUN chmod a+x  /root/nvm_install.sh
---> Using cache
---> bb13e2a2893d
Step 8 : RUN bash -c "/root/nvm_install.sh"
---> Using cache
---> 149b49a8fc71
Step 9 : RUN bash -l -c "source /root/.bashrc"
---> Running in 75f353ed0d53
---> 0eae8eae7874
Removing intermediate container 75f353ed0d53
Step 10 : RUN cd /root
---> Running in feacbd998dd0
---> 284293ef46b0
Removing intermediate container feacbd998dd0
Step 11 : RUN bash -l -c "nvm install 0.10.31"
---> Running in 388514d11067
bash: nvm: command not found
2014/09/17 13:15:11 The command [/bin/sh -c bash -l -c "nvm install 0.10.31"] returned a non-zero         code: 127
```

I'm pretty new to Docker so I may be missing something fundamental to writing Dockerfiles, but so far all the reading I've done hasn't shown me a good solution.

Comment: Not a duplicate as this is particular to installing inside docker and not a standard install

Comment: Since you're only installing a single version of node, it seems unnecessary to install nvm. The Dockerfiles provided by the Docker [node repository](https://hub.docker.com/_/node/) can be used as a reference for how to install node.

Comment: @mikwat I agree with your thinking but there are some valid use cases. For example, I'm running AWS CDK tests in a docker image and I want the node version used in the test image to dynamically update with the .nvmrc I have in my local repo. Then there's less chance that I update my node version locally but forgot to update it in the docker image.

Comment: nvm definitely makes sense for your use case @medley56

Comment: Why not use the offical node/docker image, i.e. `FROM node:xx.xx.xx`?

Answer (score 175):

When you `RUN bash...` each time that runs in a separate process, anything set in the environment is not maintained. Here's how I install `nvm`:

```bash
# Replace shell with bash so we can source files
RUN rm /bin/sh && ln -s /bin/bash /bin/sh

# Set debconf to run non-interactively
RUN echo 'debconf debconf/frontend select Noninteractive' | debconf-set-selections

# Install base dependencies
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y -q --no-install-recommends \
        apt-transport-https \
        build-essential \
        ca-certificates \
        curl \
        git \
        libssl-dev \
        wget \
    && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

ENV NVM_DIR /usr/local/nvm # or ~/.nvm , depending
ENV NODE_VERSION 0.10.33

# Install nvm with node and npm
RUN curl https://raw.githubusercontent.com/creationix/nvm/v0.20.0/install.sh | bash \
    && . $NVM_DIR/nvm.sh \
    && nvm install $NODE_VERSION \
    && nvm alias default $NODE_VERSION \
    && nvm use default

ENV NODE_PATH $NVM_DIR/v$NODE_VERSION/lib/node_modules
ENV PATH      $NVM_DIR/v$NODE_VERSION/bin:$PATH
```

Comment: to speed up it in twice just change `v0.20.0` to `v0.24.1`

Comment: with nvm `0.31.0` and node `v4.2.3` the path is `/usr/local/nvm/versions/node/v4.2.3/bin`

Comment: @thiagoh This does not explain why the questioner's install of nvm doesn't work and the working answers do work. It has nothing to do with shells running in separate processes. It is because the question attempts to source bash.rc to load the nvm.sh file which loads the nvm command into bash, but bash.rc exits early when run non interactively, so the nvm command isn't loaded. All the successful answers source nvm.sh directly instead of doing it via bash.rc. This is the key to making this work.

Comment: Instead of replacing sh with bash, you can simply do `. $NVM_DIR/nvm.sh`, avoiding source binary.

Comment: It seems like setting the `NODE_VERSION` in the Dockerfile defeats the purpose of nvm's `.nvmrc` file.

Comment: the NVM_DIR env variable is incorrect on my box -- it is actually /root/.nvm .... might be helpful to include that info for people with my situation.

Comment: This is close, but paths need a little adjustment, should be:  ENV NODE_PATH $NVM_DIR/versions/node/v$NODE_VERSION/lib/node_modules
ENV PATH      $NVM_DIR/versions/node/v$NODE_VERSION/bin:$PATH

Comment: From other answers below: symbolic links were needed for me as well (npm, node):
RUN ln -sf $NVM_DIR/versions/node/v$NODE_VERSION/bin/npm /usr/bin/npm - I am wondering why others did not need it.

Comment: With newer versions of NVM the path to the node executable has changed (which many comments have mentioned above)

Answer (score 89):

**Update** *20/02/2020*: This solution works if you're using a `debian` base image. If you're using `ubuntu`, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60137919/7056420).

Here is the cleanest way to install `nvm` that I have found:

```
SHELL ["/bin/bash", "--login", "-c"]

RUN curl -o- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nvm-sh/nvm/v0.35.3/install.sh | bash
RUN nvm install 10.15.3
```

### Explanation

- The first line sets the Dockerfile's default shell to a **bash login shell**. Note: this means that every subsequent `RUN`, `CMD`, and `ENTRYPOINT` will be run under the current user (usually root), and source the *~/.bashrc* file if run in the [shell form](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47940538/7056420).
- The second line installs `nvm` with bash. When the script is run with bash, it appends to the *~/.bashrc* file.
- The third line installs a particular version of nodejs and uses it. The `nvm`, `npm`, and `node` commands are available because they are run via a bash login shell (see line 1).

Comment: Interesting that this was working for you. I tried something similar and everything looked fine during builds, but NPM wasn't found when I went to run the resulting image. Explicitly setting `NVM_DIR` (as shown in several of the other answers) fixed it for me.

Comment: @esmail that's strange because the first `RUN` command sets `NVM_DIR` in `~/.bashrc`.

Comment: @DominicRoy-Stang, valid point. The image I was working with uses `sh` and therefore ignores `.bashrc`. Also, are you sure `.bashrc` is really sourced before executing `RUN` commands? In my brief testing with the official `bash` image, it seemed like it wasn't.

Comment: @esmail that's what the first line (the `SHELL` instruction) addresses. It makes consecutive RUN commands use a login shell which sources the `.bashrc` file. Note: it only works if commands are run in shell mode eg. `RUN nvm --version`. It will not work if commands are run in exec mode eg. `RUN ["nvm", "--version"]`. I've updated the link I provide for shell form to hopefully make this more obvious.

Answer (score 47):

Nvm paths have changed since the accepted answer, so if you want to use a more up-to-date nvm version, you need to make a few changes.  Also, it is not necessary to remap `sh` to make it work:

```
ENV NVM_DIR /usr/local/nvm
RUN mkdir -p $NVM_DIR
RUN curl -o- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/creationix/nvm/v0.33.1/install.sh | bash
ENV NODE_VERSION v7.9.0
RUN /bin/bash -c "source $NVM_DIR/nvm.sh && nvm install $NODE_VERSION && nvm use --delete-prefix $NODE_VERSION"

ENV NODE_PATH $NVM_DIR/versions/node/$NODE_VERSION/lib/node_modules
ENV PATH      $NVM_DIR/versions/node/$NODE_VERSION/bin:$PATH
```

Not sure if you will need the `--delete-prefix` option on the `nvm use` - I did, but that may be something strange about my base image.

Comment: Life saver! If only I had seen your response 3 hours ago.

Comment: Worked for me, base image php:7.1.1

Comment: Thank you. It's crazy that someone builds a modern version manager tool without thinking about CI.

Comment: You might want to add `RUN mkdir -p $NVM_DIR`. It seems like newer versions of nvm check if the directory exists.

Comment: This is the only solution that worked for me trying to install NVM in Amazon Linux 2 in the year 2022.

Comment: Can confirm: this worked for me in November 2022 after hours of struggling. Thanks! Pro tip... always scroll down to see other answers :)

Comment: March 2023 here, only working solution too !

Comment: This should be the accepted solution since it's the only one that worked for me (Apr 2023)

Comment: The only solution working for me as well in Jan 2024, after hours of trying different approaches.

Answer (score 44):

Took me an hour or two to figure out the cleanest way to do it. --login doesn't seem to execute .bashrc so you have to supply -i to launch it in interactive mode. This causes Docker to yell at you for a bit so I only launch this way for the installation, then reset to my standard shell.

```
# Installing Node
SHELL ["/bin/bash", "--login", "-i", "-c"]
RUN curl -o- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nvm-sh/nvm/v0.35.2/install.sh | bash
RUN source /root/.bashrc && nvm install 12.14.1
SHELL ["/bin/bash", "--login", "-c"]
```

Comment: Your answer made me realize that mine doesn't work using `ubuntu` as a base image (but yours does). I was using `debian` based images. I'm not sure what's causing the discrepancy between the two. Any ideas?

Comment: I'm using ubuntu 19:10 as a base image. I will post all relevant Docker instructions so that you have an idea of what works for me. Any instructions I have left out either are not relevant or I cannot provide. I'll represent them with a comment. I'll post it in the next comment since the character limit is set too low

Comment: [Similar technique here](https://gist.github.com/remarkablemark/aacf14c29b3f01d6900d13137b21db3a#gistcomment-3067813) and this is related too: [NODE VERSION MANAGEMENT IN DOCKER CONTAINERS](https://www.kabisa.nl/tech/nvm-in-docker/)

Comment: This worked for me! Thanks!
Now, if anyone is wondering how this would look in a docker-compose file, here it goes:
`command: >
      /bin/bash -i -c "
      apt-get update &&
      apt-get install -y curl &&
      curl -o- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nvm-sh/nvm/v0.39.0/install.sh | bash &&
      source /root/.bashrc &&
      nvm install 12.4.0 &&
      nvm use 12.4.0"`

Answer (score 42):

To help everyone that are looking for a way to install the Node.js with NVM on Ubuntu (last version), I made the dockerfile below. I'm using the last version of Docker, Ubuntu, Node.js and the NVM is working properly (the $PATH was fixed). I'm using this in a production environment.

```
$ docker info \
Server Version: 1.9.1
Kernel Version: 4.1.13-boot2docker
Operating System: Boot2Docker 1.9.1 (TCL 6.4.1); master : cef800b - Fri Nov 20 19:33:59 UTC 2015

Node.js Version: stable 4.2.4 LTS
Ubuntu Version: 14.04.3
```

dockerfile:

```
FROM ubuntu:14.04.3

# Replace shell with bash so we can source files
RUN rm /bin/sh && ln -s /bin/bash /bin/sh

# make sure apt is up to date
RUN apt-get update --fix-missing
RUN apt-get install -y curl
RUN apt-get install -y build-essential libssl-dev

ENV NVM_DIR /usr/local/nvm
ENV NODE_VERSION 4.2.4

# Install nvm with node and npm
RUN curl https://raw.githubusercontent.com/creationix/nvm/v0.30.1/install.sh | bash \
    && source $NVM_DIR/nvm.sh \
    && nvm install $NODE_VERSION \
    && nvm alias default $NODE_VERSION \
    && nvm use default

ENV NODE_PATH $NVM_DIR/v$NODE_VERSION/lib/node_modules
ENV PATH      $NVM_DIR/versions/node/v$NODE_VERSION/bin:$PATH

RUN mkdir /usr/app
RUN mkdir /usr/app/log

WORKDIR /usr/app

# log dir
VOLUME /usr/app/log

# Bundle app source
COPY . /usr/app
# Install app dependencies
RUN npm install

EXPOSE  3000
CMD ["node", "server.js"]
```

Comment: should the NODE_PATH not be
ENV NODE_PATH $NVM_DIR/versions/node/v$NODE_VERSION/lib/node_modules

Comment: Hello @Sentient! I´m running this docker in a production environment (ubuntu) and local dev (OSX), both are working properly, without errors. Are you may be running an outdated NVM?

Comment: Is there a reason why I should use SUDO installing build-essential and libssl-dev? I'm not at all a seasoned DevOps.

Comment: The key is `source $NVM_DIR/nvm.sh && nvm install $NODE_VERSION`

Answer (score 39):

This is my Dockerfile ready to copy/paste in which I install the latest **nvm 2022 version** with latest **Ubuntu**

### Summarized version

For docker and linux experts

```
FROM ubuntu

ENV NVM_DIR /usr/local/nvm
ENV NODE_VERSION v16.17.0
RUN mkdir -p /usr/local/nvm && apt-get update && echo "y" | apt-get install curl
RUN curl -o- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nvm-sh/nvm/v0.39.1/install.sh | bash
RUN /bin/bash -c "source $NVM_DIR/nvm.sh && nvm install $NODE_VERSION && nvm use --delete-prefix $NODE_VERSION"
ENV NODE_PATH $NVM_DIR/versions/node/$NODE_VERSION/bin
ENV PATH $NODE_PATH:$PATH
```

### Detailed and Didactic version

```bash
FROM ubuntu

# nvm requirements
RUN apt-get update
RUN echo "y" | apt-get install curl
# nvm env vars
RUN mkdir -p /usr/local/nvm
ENV NVM_DIR /usr/local/nvm
# IMPORTANT: set the exact version
ENV NODE_VERSION v16.17.0
RUN curl -o- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nvm-sh/nvm/v0.39.1/install.sh | bash
RUN /bin/bash -c "source $NVM_DIR/nvm.sh && nvm install $NODE_VERSION && nvm use --delete-prefix $NODE_VERSION"
# add node and npm to the PATH
ENV NODE_PATH $NVM_DIR/versions/node/$NODE_VERSION/bin
ENV PATH $NODE_PATH:$PATH
RUN npm -v
RUN node -v
```

### Log

[image]

### Notes

- Set the exact version of nodejs is mandatory because if you set `nvm use v16`, **16.17.0** will be downloaded and then there is no way to get the **16.17.0** from **v16** to be set in the PATH
- To get the last version of nvm (https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nvm-sh/nvm/**v0.39.1**/install.sh) we need to check the readme https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm#install--update-script
- If you need nodejs only for build spa (example), you could use docker stages and `FROM node:16` directly

Comment: Thanks! Note that you still need to do  e.g.`CMD /bin/bash -c "source \$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh && npm start"` instead of just `CMD npm start` then, but then it does work for me.

Comment: mmmm I will try  your advice. I remember that it worked.

Comment: This dockerfile works. Just one correction, The version directory has a prefix "v". ```ENV NODE_PATH $NVM_DIR/versions/node/$NODE_VERSION/lib/node_modules
ENV PATH      $NVM_DIR/versions/node/$NODE_VERSION/bin:$PATH```

Comment: Why so many runs???

Comment: to be didactic. Use foo && bar && baz if you need

Comment: Is there any way to make sure that `nvm.sh` remains sourced for all subsequent commands?

Comment: Share the error. nvm is already sources after `ENV NODE_PATH $NVM_DIR/versions/node/$NODE_VERSION/bin`

Comment: Works with ubuntu, as of Oct '23

Comment: it blows my mind how difficult it was for me to simply run `npm run build` within a dockerfile that targets asp.net core 7 minimal apis (with a built in react SPA) - your answer FINALLY got this to work and I have a wwwroot folder with the static built files in. Thank you - but also, wtaf!? why so difficult!?

Comment: Remember that docker/linux is an isolated space without any developer tool or language installed, nor process. That is the cornerstone of his performance. Also it help us to understand that the developer machine is so different compared with a production server. Finally is not difficult. If you want to run python, java or php, you need to install and configure them. The problem is that developer environment (commonly windows users) is a utopia.

Comment: #spaceBison Also you can use docker stages, so instead to install node in a netcore image, you could use directly a nodejs image. Check this https://gist.github.com/jrichardsz/9ace2f7ce02bfd1605c3a0e920553413#file-docker-build-snippets-stages-netcore-and-nodejs-sh

Answer (score 27):

Each `RUN` in a Dockerfile is executed in a different container. So if you source a file in a container, its content will not be available in the next one.

That is why when you install an application and you need to do several steps, you must do it in the same container.

With your example:

```
ADD files/nvm_install.sh /root/
RUN chmod a+x /root/nvm_install.sh && \
  /root/nvm_install.sh && \
  source /root/.bashrc && \
  cd /root && \
  nvm install 0.10.31
```

Comment: OK, Thank you very much for the explanation. 
So I've modified my script to look like this:
`    FROM ubuntu
    MAINTAINER dficociello
    ADD files/nvm_install.sh /root/
    # Install nvm
    RUN ["/bin/bash", "-c", "rm -f /etc/nginx/nginx.conf &&    touch /root/.bashrc && apt-get update && apt-get install nginx curl -y && chmod a+x /root/nvm_install.sh && source /root/.bashrc && /root/nvm_install.sh && nvm install 0.10.31"]
ADD files/nginx.conf /etc/nginx/
EXPOSE 22
`
I get the following error:
`    /bin/bash: /root/nvm_install.sh: /bin/bash: bad interpreter: Text file busy `

Comment: This error must be linked to your line `RUN ["/bin/bash", ...]`. It must not be surrounded by `[...]` and you do not need to specify the interpreter `/bin/bash -c`.

Answer (score 17):

This is based on the top answer and works in 2018:

```
# Replace shell with bash so we can source files
RUN rm /bin/sh && ln -s /bin/bash /bin/sh

# Install base dependencies
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y -q --no-install-recommends \
        apt-transport-https \
        build-essential \
        ca-certificates \
        curl \
        git \
        libssl-dev \
        wget

ENV NVM_DIR /usr/local/nvm
ENV NODE_VERSION 8.11.3

WORKDIR $NVM_DIR

RUN curl https://raw.githubusercontent.com/creationix/nvm/master/install.sh | bash \
    && . $NVM_DIR/nvm.sh \
    && nvm install $NODE_VERSION \
    && nvm alias default $NODE_VERSION \
    && nvm use default

ENV NODE_PATH $NVM_DIR/versions/node/v$NODE_VERSION/lib/node_modules
ENV PATH      $NVM_DIR/versions/node/v$NODE_VERSION/bin:$PATH
```

Note that `nvm` is not a bash command, it is an alias. This can screw you up if you're relying on `$PATH`.

Answer (score 14):

Here is my working version

```
FROM ubuntu:14.04

# Declare constants
ENV NVM_VERSION v0.29.0
ENV NODE_VERSION v5.0.0

# Replace shell with bash so we can source files
RUN rm /bin/sh && ln -s /bin/bash /bin/sh

# Install pre-reqs
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get -y install curl build-essential

# Install NVM
RUN curl -o- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/creationix/nvm/${NVM_VERSION}/install.sh | bash

# Install NODE
RUN source ~/.nvm/nvm.sh; \
    nvm install $NODE_VERSION; \
    nvm use --delete-prefix $NODE_VERSION;
```

Took help from @abdulljibali and @shamisis answers.

Comment: Sourcing the `~/.nvm/nvm.sh` file was the key I needed.

Comment: This was the only solution that worked for me with ubuntu 16.04.2 container.

Comment: Perfect! Thank you very much, sir!

Comment: Gotta prepend `${NVM_VERSION}` in the install link with a letter "*v*" (for version).

Answer (score 10):

Based upon the suggestion in @Kuhess answer, I replaced the source command with the following in my Dockerfile

```
RUN cat ~/.nvm/nvm.sh >> installnode.sh
RUN echo "nvm install 0.10.35" >> installnode.sh
RUN sh installnode.sh
```

Answer (score 10):

25-Feb-2021
The main problem is with use of the 'source' directive, which is bash shell specific.
What worked for me was replacing 'source' with '.' for a Ubuntu 18 install.
My Dockerfile:

```
FROM ubuntu:bionic

RUN \
  apt update && \
  apt upgrade -y && \
  apt install -y curl

ENV NVM_DIR /root/.nvm
ENV NODE_VERSION 14.16

# Install nvm with node and npm
RUN curl -sL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/creationix/nvm/v0.35.3/install.sh | bash \
  && . $NVM_DIR/nvm.sh \ 
  && nvm install $NODE_VERSION
```

Comment: I was stuck on this before realising that my nvm install command was in a subsequent RUN instruction. Including it in the same RUN as the source-ing of $NVM_DIR/nvm.sh fixed it.

Answer (score 9):

I must begin with the fact that I searched all over to get a working example of `nvm` inside `docker` and I found none. Even the answers in this thread did not work.

So, I spent quite some time and came up with one that works:

```terminal
# install dependencies
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
      curl \
      npm \
      nodejs \
      git;

# compatibility fix for node on ubuntu
RUN ln -s /usr/bin/nodejs /usr/bin/node;

# install nvm
RUN curl https://raw.githubusercontent.com/creationix/nvm/v0.24.1/install.sh | sh;

# invoke nvm to install node
RUN cp -f ~/.nvm/nvm.sh ~/.nvm/nvm-tmp.sh; \
    echo "nvm install 0.12.2; nvm alias default 0.12.2" >> ~/.nvm/nvm-tmp.sh; \
    sh ~/.nvm/nvm-tmp.sh; \
    rm ~/.nvm/nvm-tmp.sh;
```

> Notice how I have installed `nodejs` via `apt-get` as well. I found that some packages don't get installed inside docker unless this is done.

Comment: yup - man - tried about a 100 solutions and only yours works - 10x!

Comment: Correct to use ~/.nvm/nvm-tmp.sh, so node versions are installed correctly inside the ~/.nvm directory

Answer (score 9):

A key difference between the attempt to get the nvm command in the question:

```
RUN bash -l -c "source /root/.bashrc"
```

which doesn't work and the attempt to do the same in the accepted answer:

```
source $NVM_DIR/nvm.sh
```

Is that the second version sources the nvm.sh script directly, whereas the original tries to do it via the .bashrc file.

The .bashrc file has a line in it early on which exits if it's being run in a non interactive shell:

```
# If not running interactively, don't do anything
case $- in
    *i*) ;;
    *) return;;
esac
```

So it never gets to the bit where it would have sourced nvm.sh which actually puts the nvm command in your shell.

I wouldn't be surprised if docker is running this stuff in a non interactive shell. This hadn't been explicitly pointed out, so I thought I would mention it as it's what caught me out when I was doing something similar with vagrant.

Comment: Thanks for finding the source of the problem. I copied the /etc/skel/.bashrc file out of the base ubuntu 19.10 image and then commented out the above offending lines. Then in my Dockerfile, I used the COPY command to copy a "corrected" /etc/skel/.bashrc to /etc/skel and only thereafter use RUN to create users with /bin/bash as their shell. Then subsequent calls to RUN ["/bin/bash", "-c", "-l", YOUR_COMMAND[S]_HERE] worked fine.

Answer (score 5):

None of these worked for me, for my `python3-onbuild` container I had to force-create symbolic links to the nvm installation.

```
# Install npm and nodejs
RUN apt-get install -y build-essential libssl-dev

RUN mkdir /root/.nvm
ENV NVM_DIR /root/.nvm
ENV NODE_VERSION 8.9.4

RUN curl -o- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/creationix/nvm/v0.33.9/install.sh | bash
RUN chmod +x $HOME/.nvm/nvm.sh
RUN . $HOME/.nvm/nvm.sh && nvm install $NODE_VERSION && nvm alias default $NODE_VERSION && nvm use default && npm install -g npm

RUN ln -sf /root/.nvm/versions/node/v$NODE_VERSION/bin/node /usr/bin/nodejs
RUN ln -sf /root/.nvm/versions/node/v$NODE_VERSION/bin/node /usr/bin/node
RUN ln -sf /root/.nvm/versions/node/v$NODE_VERSION/bin/npm /usr/bin/npm
```

Comment: Agreed. When installing in a docker container (Debian GNU/Linux 9 (stretch)), nvm ends up in `$HOME/.nvm` for me as well.

Comment: Yes, symbolic links were necessary to add to me as well. I am wondering how others did not even need it.

Answer (score 3):

I got overwhelmed going through all the dockerfiles here, so I just wanted to share the relevant copy-pastable snippet:

```
# Install node and npm
# Installing a specific version of node directly is dificult. Use `nvm` to
# install it (which installs both `node` and `npm`)

# Set this to any desired version
ENV NODE_VERSION 14.17.5
# Can be anything, but this is a good default       
ENV NVM_DIR /usr/local/nvm
# Must match one of the tag versions on https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm/tags     
ENV NVM_VERSION 0.39.5         

RUN mkdir -p $NVM_DIR \
  && curl https://raw.githubusercontent.com/creationix/nvm/v$NVM_VERSION/install.sh | bash \
  && . $NVM_DIR/nvm.sh \
  && nvm install $NODE_VERSION \
  && nvm alias default $NODE_VERSION \
  && nvm use default \
  && node -v \
  && npm -v

# Update the $PATH to make your installed `node` and `npm` available!
ENV PATH $NVM_DIR/versions/node/v$NODE_VERSION/bin:$PATH
```

Comment: `/usr/bin/mkdir: cannot create directory '/usr/local/nvm': Permission denied`

Comment: Not sure what permissions are set up on your environment, but you can change `$NVM_DIR` to any path that you are able to write to.

Comment: copy-pastable version yes, thanks! except whats not cp-able are those inline comments on the env var decls :D

Comment: works here with my edits, thanks again!!

Comment: @AlexeySh. thats odd in a docker build. seems something is off in your base image, or whatever is done before running this. this works here from ubuntu:20.04 image as base.

Answer (score 2):

This is what worked for me (I'm using debian buster):

```
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install -y build-essential checkinstall libssl-dev
RUN curl -o- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/creationix/nvm/v0.35.1/install.sh | bash
SHELL ["/bin/bash", "--login", "-c"]
```

You should now be able to do `nvm install <version>`.

Answer (score 2):

This installs the lts-version of nodejs when extending image "php:7.4.15" (debian:buster-slim):

```
# Install nvm to install npm and node.js
ENV NVM_DIR /root/.nvm
ENV NODE_VERSION lts/*
RUN mkdir $HOME/.nvm && \
    curl -o- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nvm-sh/nvm/v0.37.2/install.sh | bash && \
    chmod +x $HOME/.nvm/nvm.sh && \
    . $HOME/.nvm/nvm.sh && \
    nvm install --latest-npm "$NODE_VERSION" && \
    nvm alias default "$NODE_VERSION" && \
    nvm use default && \
    DEFAULT_NODE_VERSION=$(nvm version default) && \
    ln -sf /root/.nvm/versions/node/$DEFAULT_NODE_VERSION/bin/node /usr/bin/nodejs && \
    ln -sf /root/.nvm/versions/node/$DEFAULT_NODE_VERSION/bin/node /usr/bin/node && \
    ln -sf /root/.nvm/versions/node/$DEFAULT_NODE_VERSION/bin/npm /usr/bin/npm
```

Comment: I upvoted it, but was going to remove the upvote because this installs it as root, so npm won't be able to write to files which are not owned by root.

Answer (score 2):

`nvm not found` can result from it being installed for a different user than the one who is executing the container. You may need to prefix the installation with the custom user who is executing the container. The last `USER` statement defines the container user.

```
USER $USERNAME

RUN curl -o- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nvm-sh/nvm/v0.39.1/install.sh | bash
```

**Reason**

Diving into a `nvm` install script, e. g. [v0.39.1](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nvm-sh/nvm/v0.39.1/install.sh), one can see that is installed into `$HOME` of the current user. If you have not changed it, the default user of a `ubuntu` image is `root`. When starting the container with a different user however, `nvm` won't be found; hence make sure user of installation and execution align.

```sh
nvm_default_install_dir() {
  [ -z "${XDG_CONFIG_HOME-}" ] && printf %s "${HOME}/.nvm" || printf %s "${XDG_CONFIG_HOME}/nvm"
}
```

Answer (score 2):

After testing most information here as well as other posts, turned out in my case it was related to permission issues, that lead to weird bugs, like failing to install a npm project unless run as root user, my setup was to run VueJs along a PHP CMS, the final portion that worked was:

```
ENV NVM_DIR $TMP_STORE/nvm
ENV NODE_VERSION 16.15.0

RUN chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www/

USER www-data
RUN export XDG_CONFIG_HOME=$TMP_STORE \
    && curl -o- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nvm-sh/nvm/v0.39.1/install.sh | bash

#RUN chown -R www-data:www-data $NVM_DIR

RUN source $NVM_DIR/nvm.sh \
    && nvm install $NODE_VERSION \
    && nvm alias default $NODE_VERSION \
    && nvm use default

ENV NODE_PATH $NVM_DIR/v$NODE_VERSION/lib/node_modules
ENV PATH $NVM_DIR/versions/node/v$NODE_VERSION/bin:$PATH

RUN npm install -g @vue/cli \
    && npm install -g vue

USER root
```

The whole docker configuration can be found [here](https://github.com/Trotalo/modxBaseEnviroment)

Answer (score 2):

2022 update:

based off https://stackoverflow.com/a/60137919/2047472 I came up with:

```
FROM python:3.10

RUN touch .profile

SHELL ["/bin/bash", "--login", "-i", "-c"]
RUN curl -o- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nvm-sh/nvm/v0.39.1/install.sh | bash
SHELL ["/bin/bash", "--login", "-c"]

RUN nvm install
RUN node -v
RUN npm -v
```

- if you use `.nvmrc` and use source to init nvm, beware of a [bug](https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm/issues/1985) in nvm.sh causing it to exit with return code 3 when `.nvmrc` is present in current or parent directory
- I had to touch `.profile` as it didn't exist, otherwise nvm is not activated in subsequent RUN commands

  - `touch .bashrc` didn't work

Answer (score 2):

### 2023 to use as dev-container

I started to use the dev-contieners and to set up my enviroment I used the next `Dockcerfile` that works perfectly with the purpose I've described. I share this because spend a hard time to achive it.

```
FROM ubuntu:22.04
ENV HOME="/root"
ENV NVM_DIR="${HOME}/.nvm"
ENV NVM_VERSION=v0.39.3
ENV NODE_VERSION=18

RUN apt-get update \
    && apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends build-essential\
        libssl-dev \
        git \
        curl \
        ca-certificates \
    && git clone https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm.git "${NVM_DIR}" 
WORKDIR  "${NVM_DIR}"
RUN git checkout ${NVM_VERSION} \
    && \. "./nvm.sh" \
    && nvm install "${NODE_VERSION}" \
    && echo '[ -s "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh" ] && \. "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh"' >> "${HOME}/.bashrc" \
    && echo '[ -s "$NVM_DIR/bash_completion" ] && \. "$NVM_DIR/bash_completion"' >> "${HOME}/.bashrc"  

WORKDIR "${HOME}"
```

This is intended to work with bash (I don't have idea if works with another type of shell). The command that I used to run the image was:

```bash
 docker run -ti --rm --name node_test <your-image-name | id-image> /bin/bash
```

Answer (score 1):

Also had an oddly hard time for my docker file extending the CircleCI runner image - this worked for me:

```
FROM circleci/runner:launch-agent
SHELL ["/bin/bash", "--login", "-c"]

USER $USERNAME

RUN wget -qO- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nvm-sh/nvm/v0.39.2/install.sh | bash;

ENV NODE_VERSION 18.12.1

ENV NVM_DIR $HOME/.nvm

RUN \
    . ~/.nvm/nvm.sh \
    && nvm install $NODE_VERSION \
    && nvm alias default $NODE_VERSION \
    && nvm use default;


ENV NODE_PATH $NVM_DIR/v$NODE_VERSION/lib/node_modules
ENV PATH      $NVM_DIR/versions/node/v$NODE_VERSION/bin:$PATH

RUN npm -v
RUN node -v
```

Comment: why is there a single line `RUN \`. What's that for

Comment: @user1034912 the backslash after RUN is an escape (ignore the character after the escape), so the new line is ignored. Each backslash at the end of the line essentially allows you to separate each command with a new line (instead of having that chain on one line)

Answer (score 0):

I had a really hard time getting NVM working properly on an alpine-based image. I ultimately just copied over a bunch of the shared directories from an official Node alpine image. Seems to be working quite well so far.

```
# Dockerfile

###############################################################################
# https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/multistage-build/
# Builder Image
# This image is intended to build the app source code, not to run it.
###############################################################################
FROM node:16-alpine as builder

WORKDIR /build-tmp

COPY ./dist/src/yarn.lock .
COPY ./dist/src/package.json .
RUN yarn install --production

###############################################################################
# Execution image
# Nothing from the builder image is included here unless explicitly copied
###############################################################################
FROM osgeo/gdal:alpine-normal-3.4.2

# It's seemingly very difficult to build a specific version of node in an Alpine linux
# image, so let's copy node from the builder image into this execution image!
COPY --from=builder /usr/lib /usr/lib
COPY --from=builder /usr/local/share /usr/local/share
COPY --from=builder /usr/local/lib /usr/local/lib
COPY --from=builder /usr/local/include /usr/local/include
COPY --from=builder /usr/local/bin /usr/local/bin

...

CMD ["node", "main"]
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution I recently used:

```bash
# Install nvm/Node.js
ENV NVM_VERSION=0.39.1
ENV NODE_VERSION=16.17.1
RUN curl -o- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nvm-sh/nvm/v$NVM_VERSION/install.sh | bash
RUN bash --login -c "nvm install $NODE_VERSION"

# Do whatever with nvm
RUN bash --login -c "nvm use $NODE_VERSION && npm [...]"
```

Answer (score 0):

and here is a version invariant that just gets latest lts

```
ENV NVM_DIR /root/.nvm
RUN mkdir -p $NVM_DIR && curl https://raw.githubusercontent.com/creationix/nvm/master/install.sh | bash && . ~/.bashrc && nvm install --lts
RUN . $NVM_DIR/nvm.sh && ln -s $NVM_DIR/$(nvm current) $NVM_DIR/cur && ln -s $NVM_DIR/versions/node/$(nvm current) $NVM_DIR/versions/node/cur
ENV NODE_PATH $NVM_DIR/cur/lib/node_modules
ENV PATH      $NVM_DIR/versions/node/cur/bin:$PATH
```

Answer (score 0):

2024

I have been struggling with this since 2022 trying to set up a circle ci machine to run a simple playwright test. I ended up using `run: | curl nvm | bash etc.` and basically treating as if i were sshed into the machine

enter root

```
USER root
```

yes ik this is not secure, but what can a few lines hurt to curl nvm and do what you're probably familiar with:

```
RUN mkdir -p $NVM_DIR; curl -o- https://nvm-dl-link/install.sh | bash 
RUN .  "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh"
etc.
```

then you just change back to whatever user you want, which on ubuntu 20 for me is `circleci`

Answer (score -1):

Another cleanish solution for those who only have sh shell installed, or depends on sh shell.
The difference between this and other solutions is the fact that you have to alter PATH for node bin to be available in another shell. Hopefully it helps.

```
# install node with nvm and within bash, then carry node bin to sh
SHELL ["/bin/bash", "--login", "-c"]
ENV NODE 14.21.3 
ENV NODE_BIN /root/.nvm/versions/node/v$NODE/bin/
RUN curl -o- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nvm-sh/nvm/v0.39.3/install.sh | bash
RUN nvm install $NODE
ENV PATH="${PATH}:${NODE_BIN}"
SHELL ["/bin/sh", "-c"]
```

replace 14.21.3 and 0.39.3 with desired node and nvm versions

Comment: nvm not found !

Comment: @AshishSaini if you are trying to call nvm out of SHELL /SHELL block then it won't be available. You would need to keep using bash in your env

Comment: didnt here for me, https://stackoverflow.com/a/76156862/589493 was working