# Docker(compose) installing nodejs broke npm

Tags: node.js, nginx, docker, npm, docker-compose

I need to use a container with nginx and nodejs, so I take the nginx container and install the node:

```
FROM nginx

ENV DEBIAN_FRONTEND noninteractive

WORKDIR /usr/src/app
VOLUME /usr/src/app


RUN apt-get update && \
  apt-get install -y apt-utils && \
  apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends curl sudo wget nano && \
  curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_6.x | bash - && \
  apt-get install -y nodejs git build-essential && \
  whereis npm && \
  npm install grunt grunt-cli bower -g && \
```

`whereis` returnme nothing `npm:`, and `npm install...` crash the build proccess. so Where ir my mistake, is there a bug or anything? btw I'm using latest docker-compose and Docker version 17.03.1-ce, build c6d412e

Update 1: It is not a dupe of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25899912/install-nvm-in-docker), I'm only using one RUN line

Comment: @NazariiBardiuk it'snot a dup, because I'm only using a single RUN, also this dockerfile used to work last month

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
FROM nginx

RUN \
    echo 'debconf debconf/frontend select Noninteractive' | debconf-set-selections && \
    apt-get update && \
    apt-get install -y apt-utils && \
    apt-get upgrade -y && \
    apt-get update --fix-missing && \
    apt-get install -y curl sudo wget nano git build-essential

# Install NodeJS
RUN \
    wget https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_6.x && \
    chmod +x setup_6.x && \
    ./setup_6.x && \
    apt-get install -y nodejs && \
    npm install grunt grunt-cli
```