# Installing specific node.js version in Dockerfile

Tags: node.js, dockerfile

I was trying to install Node.js of version 14.17.3 with Dockerfile -

```
FROM jetbrains/teamcity-agent:2022.10.1-linux-sudo

RUN curl -s https://packages.cloud.google.com/apt/doc/apt-key.gpg | sudo apt-key add -
RUN sudo sh -c 'echo deb https://apt.kubernetes.io/ kubernetes-xenial main > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/kubernetes.list'

RUN curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_16.x | sudo -E bash -

# https://github.com/AdoptOpenJDK/openjdk-docker/blob/master/12/jdk/ubuntu/Dockerfile.hotspot.releases.full
RUN sudo apt-get update && \
    sudo apt-get install -y ffmpeg gnupg2 git sudo kubectl \
    binfmt-support qemu-user-static mc jq
RUN sudo apt install -y cmake build-essential wget

ENV NODE_VERSION=14.17.3
RUN curl -o- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nvm-sh/nvm/v0.39.0/install.sh | bash
ENV NVM_DIR=$HOME/root/.nvm
RUN sudo bash "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh" && sudo nvm install ${NODE_VERSION}
RUN sudo bash "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh" && sudo nvm use v${NODE_VERSION}
RUN sudo bash "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh" && sudo nvm alias default v${NODE_VERSION}
ENV PATH="$HOME/.nvm/versions/node/v${NODE_VERSION}/bin/:${PATH}"
RUN node --version
RUN npm --version
```

However, it has failed with following logs:

```
20:05:25   Step 10/27 : RUN sudo bash "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh" && sudo nvm install ${NODE_VERSION}
20:05:28    ---> Running in 533e65e26299
20:05:29   bash: /root/.nvm/nvm.sh: No such file or directory
20:05:29   The command '/bin/sh -c sudo bash "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh" && sudo nvm install ${NODE_VERSION}' returned a non-zero code: 127
```

Comment: When you install nvm with `curl` you are running as current user when you pipe to bash. You need to run it as the sudo if you are going to do that with everything else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a solution for [building a Docker image with nvm](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57344191/3592771), which includes running the install commands under a login shell.

Regardless, note that you need to make sure that the installation directory ($NVM_DIR) exists before you install nvm-sh. Since the Base docker [run under a non-admin user](https://hub.docker.com/r/jetbrains/teamcity-agent/) you cannot set it to be under the root user.

See an example for Dockerfile below which works based on provided solution:

```
FROM jetbrains/teamcity-agent:2022.10.1-linux-sudo

RUN curl -s https://packages.cloud.google.com/apt/doc/apt-key.gpg | sudo apt-key add -
RUN sudo sh -c 'echo deb https://apt.kubernetes.io/ kubernetes-xenial main > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/kubernetes.list'

RUN curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_16.x | sudo -E bash -

# https://github.com/AdoptOpenJDK/openjdk-docker/blob/master/12/jdk/ubuntu/Dockerfile.hotspot.releases.full
RUN sudo apt-get update && \
    sudo apt-get install -y ffmpeg gnupg2 git sudo kubectl \
    binfmt-support qemu-user-static mc jq
RUN sudo apt install -y cmake build-essential wget

SHELL ["/bin/bash", "--login", "-c"]

ENV NODE_VERSION=14.17.3
ENV NVM_DIR /tmp/nvm
WORKDIR $NVM_DIR

RUN curl -o- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nvm-sh/nvm/v0.39.0/install.sh | bash \
  && . $NVM_DIR/nvm.sh \
  && nvm install $NODE_VERSION \
  && nvm alias default $NODE_VERSION \
  && nvm use default

ENV NODE_PATH $NVM_DIR/v$NODE_VERSION/lib/node_modules
ENV PATH      $NVM_DIR/v$NODE_VERSION/bin:$PATH

RUN node --version
RUN npm --version
```