# nvm is working in bash shell but not in sh shell

Tags: node.js, docker, jenkins, nvm

```
RUN curl --silent -o- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/creationix/nvm/v0.39.1/install.sh |          bash - && \ 
    . $HOME/.nvm/nvm.sh && \
    nvm ls && \
    chmod -R 777 /bin/ && \ 
    nvm install 18 && \
    nvm install 16 && \
    nvm install 14 && \
    nvm alias default 14 && \
    nvm use default && \
    nvm ls && \
    node -v
```

I need nvm to build multiple node versions. I am using this on my Jenkins docker agent. But in Jenkins, I got nvm not found.

Comment: A Docker container only runs one program, and correspondingly an image usually only has one version of its language runtime installed in it.  Can you use the `node:14`, `node:16`, or `node:18` images as appropriate, without a version manager?

Comment: The `. nvm.sh` line doesn't persist beyond the current `RUN` line, which could be your technical issue.  Does [How to install nvm in docker?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25899912/how-to-install-nvm-in-docker) address this for you?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to install nvm in docker?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25899912/how-to-install-nvm-in-docker)

Comment: i want to add multiple node versions support in my jenkins agent. nvm is working on agent when i login manually. but when jenkins up a slave agent then in the logs i found that nvm is not found

Comment: how i can load bashrc file in jenkins build or can change default shell of jenkins agent?

Answer (score 0):

I was googling if this was a known problem because I just stumbled over the same, if not very similar problem. nvm for some reason expects an interactive bash shell and for their stuff to work once that "." command is in bashrc.

NVM was written assuming that you will just run it in an interactive bash shell. See for example this snippet from the end of nvm.sh:

```
nvm_process_parameters() {
  local NVM_AUTO_MODE
  NVM_AUTO_MODE='use'
  while [ $# -ne 0 ]; do
    case "$1" in
      --install) NVM_AUTO_MODE='install' ;;
      --no-use) NVM_AUTO_MODE='none' ;;
    esac 
    shift
  done 
  nvm_auto "${NVM_AUTO_MODE}"
}
```

That `$#` simply does not work in the bourne shell, hence the script always sets 'use' as NVM_AUTO_MODE.

Your problem is probable different. But the bottom line is : install bash in your container, and run it under bash.

```
bash -c " . $HOME/.nvm/nvm.sh ; nvm ls ; "
```

Also, I would put in a few more checks and steps to add the file you're straight piping into a shell from wget, and make that a COPY step or something.

Comment: Thanks @Frank Van Damme we are able to solve problem using this-  

`
RUN curl https://raw.githubusercontent.com/creationix/nvm/master/install.sh | bash - && \ 
        bash -l -c ". $HOME/.nvm/nvm.sh ; nvm install 18; nvm install 16; nvm install 14; nvm 
        ls;  nvm alias default 14; nvm use default; node -v"

RUN echo "export NVM_DIR=$HOME/.nvm" >> ~/.profile \
    && echo ". $HOME/.nvm/nvm.sh" >> ~/.profile
`

Answer (score 0):

```
RUN curl https://raw.githubusercontent.com/creationix/nvm/master/install.sh | bash - && \ 
      bash -l -c ". $HOME/.nvm/nvm.sh ; nvm install 18; nvm install 16; nvm install 14; nvm ls; nvm alias default 14; nvm use default; node -v"

RUN echo "export NVM_DIR=$HOME/.nvm" >> ~/.profile \
    && echo ". $HOME/.nvm/nvm.sh" >> ~/.profile
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved by adding more information on what the code does and how it solved your problem.