# www-data user cant access node inside of docker container terminal

Tags: node.js, linux, docker, dockerfile, debian

I installed node and npm using nvm in my Dockerfile when running the build method everything runs smoothly with no problems going inside of my docker container terminal though and trying to access node, npm or nvm I get a error message that neither node npm or nvm to be found.

At first I thought its something wrong with the way I am downloading it but after some testing I found out that I can access node only with other users such as root or my other user not with `www-data`

**I tried these solutions and none of them worked:**

1. Changing the permissions of the files to 777, 755 or 640.
2. Checked the users and group owners of the files and they are all set to `www-data www-data` .
3. Added sudo to www-data

(I am using: `nginx` `debian` `php8.2` and I am trying to download `node 18` )
(inside of my shell I am using `bin/bash` and I am running the  `source /var/www/.bashrc`
`source /etc/bash.bashrc`)

```
RUN ls -la \
    && mkdir "/var/www/.nvm" \
    && export NVM_DIR="/var/www/.nvm" \
    && curl -o- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nvm-sh/nvm/v0.39.1/install.sh | bash \
    && [ -s "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh" ] && \. "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh" \
    && [ -s "$NVM_DIR/bash_completion" ] && \. "$NVM_DIR/bash_completion"  \
    && nvm install 18 \
    && nvm use 18 && npm install -g yarn \
    && nvm use 18 \
    && nvm alias default 18

ENV NODE_PATH $NVM_DIR/v$NODE_VERSION/lib/node_modules
ENV PATH      $NVM_DIR/v$NODE_VERSION/bin:$PATH
```

Comment: Version managers like `nvm` tend to not work well in Docker: most paths to running things in Docker don't read shell dotfiles, for example.  Since a container only runs a single application, can you change your Dockerfile to be built `FROM node:18` and avoid this step entirely?

Comment: hey @DavidMaze unfortunately not my task require me to use the ```FROM debian```

Comment: Does [How to install nvm in docker?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25899912/how-to-install-nvm-in-docker) answer your question?

Comment: @DavidMaze no not really I still have the problem where I cant access node with the www-data user

Comment: its only when I go in bash I am able to access the node

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed the problem where I inserted a soft link inside of the `/usr/local/bin` that leads to the **node** and **npm** inside of the : `/var/www/.nvm/versions/node/myNodeVersion/bin/` with this I was able to access the **npm** and **node** inside of the linux shell system (**POSIX**).

and I inserted the code that creates the soft links inside of my entrypoint shell:

```
#!/bin/bash


set -e

source /var/www/.bashrc

export BASH_ENV=/var/www/.bashrc

if [[ ! -z "$NODE_VERSION" ]]; then
   nvm alias default ${NODE_VERSION}
   sudo rm -f /usr/local/bin/node
   sudo rm -f /usr/local/bin/npm
   sudo ln -s "$(which node)" "/usr/local/bin/node"
   sudo ln -s "$(which npm)" "/usr/local/bin/npm"
fi
```

Comment: ```myNodeVersion = $NODE_VERSION``` which is for my case v18