# Yarn command not found after successful docker build

Tags: node.js, docker, yarnpkg, amazon-linux

Hi I am using `amazonlinux:2` as my docker image and i am trying to install `nodev14` from `nvm` I did not find any alternatives to do that I am trying to install `yarn`. Here's my `Dockerfile`

```
FROM amazonlinux:2

RUN yum update -y && \
    yum install tar curl gzip -y && \
    curl -o- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nvm-sh/nvm/v0.39.5/install.sh | bash && \
    . ~/.nvm/nvm.sh && \
    nvm install 14 -y &&  \
    npm install yarn -g && \
    yum install aws-cli -y && \
    yum clean all
```

When I build it is get build successful but when I run `docker run -it container /bin/bash` and after I get on `/bin/bash`  it says command not found.
Here's the full log for it

```
niteshrijal@Niteshs-MBP creepler % docker build -t node-14-tst .
[+] Building 50.9s (7/7) FINISHED                                                                           docker:desktop-linux
 => [internal] load build definition from Dockerfile                                                                        0.0s
 => => transferring dockerfile: 377B                                                                                        0.0s
 => [internal] load .dockerignore                                                                                           0.0s
 => => transferring context: 2B                                                                                             0.0s
 => [internal] load metadata for docker.io/library/amazonlinux:2                                                            2.5s
 => [auth] library/amazonlinux:pull token for registry-1.docker.io                                                          0.0s
 => CACHED [1/2] FROM docker.io/library/amazonlinux:2@sha256:7c24b50b9f0ad83b7219edb704962f361bcf3ec85fdfd302121159bf0d0a6  0.0s
 => [2/2] RUN yum update -y &&     yum install tar curl gzip -y &&     curl -o- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nvm-sh/  47.5s
 => exporting to image                                                                                                      0.8s
 => => exporting layers                                                                                                     0.8s
 => => writing image sha256:bd8ae162aadb85eb1e08ac987f4cf136a7e604d7eac16231205d20ccab134e9a                                0.0s 
 => => naming to docker.io/library/node-14-tst                                                                              0.0s 

What's Next?
  View summary of image vulnerabilities and recommendations → docker scout quickview
niteshrijal@Niteshs-MBP creepler % docker run -it node-14-tst /bin/bash

bash-4.2# yarn
bash: yarn: command not found
```

Comment: Does [How to install nvm in docker?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25899912/how-to-install-nvm-in-docker) answer your question?  Also consider that a Docker image usually contains a single packaged application and its dependencies, which means it shouldn't ever need more than one version of Node; can you directly install the version of Node you need without nvm, or just build your image `FROM node:14`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your NVM environment is not getting activated.
When you install NVM, it attempts to add some stuff to your environment/PATH in the correct profile. If it fails to find a proper profile file, it will fail to do this. It also cannot know if you will be connecting to your container via bash, sh, zsh, or perhaps some other shell, and therefore it really cannot know which file to add your variables to. This is why the NVM readme specifies that it **attempts** to add variables to the correct profile.

Try creating .bashrc file in the home directory of your container with the following contents, as mentioned in the [NVM readme](https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm#install--update-script):

```
export NVM_DIR="$([ -z "${XDG_CONFIG_HOME-}" ] && printf %s "${HOME}/.nvm" || printf %s "${XDG_CONFIG_HOME}/nvm")"
[ -s "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh" ] && \. "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh" # This loads nvm
```

You could do this by creating the .bashrc file in the same folder as your Dockerfile and then just copying it:

```
COPY .bashrc /root/.bashrc
```

Comment: this answers my question but yarn is not install in /bin/sh I got problem there

Comment: I would probably just suggest not using NVM inside Docker as it's mostly a development tool. Instead, use a Node base image, as @DavidMaze suggested. It will be a far smoother experience.

Comment: If you absolutely need Amazon Linux, you can download and run the script at https://rpm.nodesource.com/setup_14.x (via CURL, for example) and then you can run `yum install nodejs -y` which will install Node 14 in your Amazon Linux image directly without requiring any profile variables to be loaded.