# How to solve Docker container exec format error for running entrypoint

Tags: node.js, linux, docker, amazon-ecs, yarnpkg

Perviously the question was related to [Yarn command not found after successful docker build](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77266768/yarn-command-not-found-after-successful-docker-build). But it was fixed but my problem is related to using shell `/bin/sh` Here's What I am trying to do use `yarn` and install it on `amazonlinux:2` image Here's my Dockerfile

```
FROM amazonlinux:2

RUN yum update -y && \
    yum install -y tar curl gzip zip unzip aws-cli

RUN curl -o- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nvm-sh/nvm/v0.39.5/install.sh | sh && \
    . ~/.nvm/nvm.sh && \
    nvm install 14 && \
    nvm alias default 14 && \
    nvm use default && \
    npm install -g yarn

USER root

COPY .bashrc /root/.bashrc

COPY entrypoint.sh /root/entrypoint.sh

RUN chmod +x /root/entrypoint.sh

ENTRYPOINT [ "/root/entrypoint.sh" ]
```

And this is my `.bashrc` file

```
#!/bin/sh
export NVM_DIR="$([ -z "${XDG_CONFIG_HOME-}" ] && printf %s "${HOME}/.nvm" || printf %s "${XDG_CONFIG_HOME}/nvm")"
[ -s "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh" ] && \. "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh"
```

ANd this is my `entrypoint.sh`

```
#!/bin/sh
. /root/.bashrc
exec "$@"
```

All I get is while trying to run container from ECS  `exec /root/entrypoint.sh: exec format error` and `Essential container in task exited` How to solve the exec format error?Please help me

Comment: (Can you build your image `FROM node:14`, and delete basically all of the other code you show here?  @MarkB's [answer](/a/77287859) about making sure the build and target architectures matchi will still apply.)

Comment: Can you post the `docker run` command ?

Comment: @Philippe it's running from aws ecs

Comment: Can you get the `docker run` command ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `exec format error` message means that you have built your docker image on an ARM system like a Mac M1, and are trying to run it on an X86 system, or the opposite, building it on an X86 computer and trying to run it on an ARM system like an AWS Graviton environment.

You either need to use [Docker BuildKit](https://docs.docker.com/build/building/multi-platform/) to build the image for the environment you intend to run it, or make sure that your build environment and deployment environment have the same CPU architecture.

Comment: This won't help as I tried building it from amazon linux 2 the same error `Essential container in task exited`

Comment: The operating system (in this case Amazon Linux 2) is not the thing at issue here. The CPU architecture of the underlying computer is the issue. Changing what operating system you build the docker container on will not fix anything.

Comment: Are you deploying to X86 or Graviton instances on ECS?

Comment: I using fargate for it so it is x86

Comment: @Neetesshhr Fargate supports both X86 and Graviton... https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/announcing-aws-graviton2-support-for-aws-fargate-get-up-to-40-better-price-performance-for-your-serverless-containers/

Comment: it's x86 architecture i.e x86_64

Comment: OK then where are you building your docker image? Are you building it on an M1 mac or something? If you have an ARM based docker image, why not switch to using a Graviton Fargate deployment?

Comment: I used M2 chip but switched to amazon linux server x64 bit for it