# Why image not created?

Tags: docker, npm, dockerfile, nvm

I have that Dockerfile

```
FROM ubuntu:22.04

WORKDIR /root/app/frontend

COPY . .

ENV APP_NAME app.com
ENV CONTAINER_PORT 80
ENV NODE_VERSION v20.10

EXPOSE $CONTAINER_PORT

# utils
RUN apt-get update \
    && apt-get install -y systemd \
    && apt-get install -y curl \
    && apt-get install -y sudo \
    && apt-get install -y git \
    && apt-get install -y vim \
    && apt-get install -y nginx

# nvm settings
RUN git clone https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm.git /root/.nvm \
    && chmod -R 777 /root/.nvm/ \ 
    && bash /root/.nvm/install.sh \
    && bash -i -c 'nvm ls-remote' \ 
    && bash -i -c 'nvm install $NODE_VERSION' \
    && bash -i -c 'nvm use $NODE_VERSION' 

# nginx settings
RUN sudo rm /etc/nginx/sites-available/default \
    && sudo rm /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default \
    && bash ./.nginx/nginx.sh \
    && ln -s /etc/nginx/sites-available/$APP_NAME /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/$APP_NAME \
    && gpasswd -a www-data root \
    && chmod g+x /root && chmod g+x /root/app && chmod g+x /root/app/frontend

RUN chmod -R 777 /root/.npm/ 
RUN npm i

CMD ["nginx", "-g", "daemon off;"]
```

I try to create image with `docker image build --file Dockerfile --tag front ./`

and have that problem

> ### 39 | >>> RUN npm i
>
> ERROR: failed to solve: process "/bin/sh -c npm i" did not complete successfully: exit code: 127

I try replace this row on `RUN bash -i -c 'npm i'`

and it never finished

please help me

Comment: I suggest that the command `npm i` is executed in a non package directory (no package.json available) or did you missed some arguments for `npm i`, see the docs https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v10/commands/npm-install

Comment: Can you show what the docker build context is?

Comment: Docker doesn't usually read shell dotfiles, and the `nvm use` command doesn't have any effect on later `RUN` commands.  Also see [How to install nvm in docker?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25899912/how-to-install-nvm-in-docker)  I'd consider scrapping most of this Dockerfile and just building it `FROM node:20.10`, with a second stage `FROM nginx:1.25` if you want to use Nginx to serve the built application.

Comment: @Easterwood, how to do it?) in my project folder exist package.json at the same nesting level as Dockerfile

Comment: I suggest you to follow the comment from @DavidMaze

Comment: The error message you've posted is a generic NPM error message that just says that something went wrong. Earlier in the NPM log there should be a more precise error message.

Answer (score 0):

It was solution for me:

RUN ln -sf $USER_DIR/.nvm/versions/node/v20.10.0/bin/nodejs /bin/nodejs 
&& ln -sf $USER_DIR/.nvm/versions/node/v20.10.0/bin/node /bin/node 
&& ln -sf $USER_DIR/.nvm/versions/node/v20.10.0/bin/npm /bin/npm

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).