# Segmentation Fault When Running ng serve Docker Container

Tags: angular, docker, segmentation-fault, ng-build

When trying to run a container built from this dockerfile, I keep getting an error `/home/web/frontendstart.sh: line 25: ng: command not found` and then a segmentation fault when it reaches the final line in frontendstart.sh,`ng serve --port 8081 --host 0.0.0.0` .

Docker Version: 4.19.0
Mac OS: 14.3
Processor: Intel

Dockerfile

```
# Base image ubuntu cause its easy
FROM ubuntu:latest AS base
LABEL project="LimbRescue"
LABEL release="DEV"

# Configure Routes
# TODO see if we can remove (this should not be necessary with docker-compose)
EXPOSE 8443/tcp

# Get needed software from apt, 
# remove apt lists to save space
RUN apt-get update \
    && apt-get -y install \
        git \ 
        mysql-server \
        maven \
        nginx \
        curl \
    && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

RUN useradd -ms /bin/bash web

USER web

# Installs the long term support version of nodejs, 
# NOTE: this may be newer than apt-get nodejs as found out on 6/10/22
# I understand that "curl <url> | bash" is bad practice. This seems to be the only way 
#   to get nvm, and nvm is way we have to manage node version since apt-get can have
#   very old versions of nodejs. If a better way becomes avalible then please use it. 
# Weird shell commands because nvm wants to use ~/.bashrc solution found below:  
# https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25899912/how-to-install-nvm-in-docker/60137919#60137919
SHELL ["/bin/bash", "--login", "-i", "-c"]
RUN curl -o- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nvm-sh/nvm/v0.39.1/install.sh | bash
ENV NODE_OPTIONS="--max_old_space_size=4096 --openssl-legacy-provider"
RUN source /home/web/.bashrc \
    && nvm install --lts
SHELL ["/bin/bash", "--login", "-c"]

FROM base AS setup

# Sets up the sql server
USER root
WORKDIR /root
COPY src/* .
COPY src/dev/* .
COPY data/* .
RUN /bin/bash setup.sh
RUN chmod +x /root/start.sh

# Starts the front/backend servers
FROM setup AS start

WORKDIR /home/web
#ENTRYPOINT /bin/bash;
ENTRYPOINT /root/start.sh; tail -f /dev/null
```

Start.sh

```
service mysql start
# try moving backend start
if test -f "/root/backendstart.sh"; then 
    mv /root/backendstart.sh /home/web/backendstart.sh
    chown web:web /home/web/backendstart.sh
else
    echo "/root/backendstart.sh not found, may have already been moved to /home/web"
fi
# try moving front end start
if test -f "/root/frontendstart.sh"; then
    mv /root/frontendstart.sh /home/web/frontendstart.sh
    chown web:web /home/web/frontendstart.sh
else
    echo "/root/frontendstart.sh not found, may have already been moved to /home/web"
fi
# check for backend start
if test -f "/home/web/backendstart.sh"; then
    su -c "/bin/bash /home/web/backendstart.sh &" web
else
    echo "Could not find /home/web/backendstart.sh?? unable to continue"
fi
# Check for frontend start
if test -f "/home/web/frontendstart.sh"; then
    su -c "/bin/bash /home/web/frontendstart.sh &" web
else
    echo "Could not find /home/web/frontendstart.sh?? unable to continue"
fi
```

Frontendstart.sh

```
#!/bin/bash


# Stolen from .bashrc
# Makes npm work
export NVM_DIR="$HOME/.nvm"

# This loads nvm
[ -s "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh" ] && \. "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh"

# This loads nvm bash_completion
[ -s "$NVM_DIR/bash_completion" ] && \. "$NVM_DIR/bash_completion"

# Updates our code and starts the npm server
cd /home/web/LimbRescueAngularAppFrontend/LimbRescue

# Development specific globals
cp src/app/global/Constants-dev.ts src/app/global/Constants.ts

echo "Upgrading NPM"
npm upgrade

echo "Installing npm packages"
npm install
ng update
npm update

echo "Installing angular/cli "
npm install -g @angular/cli
npm install -g @angular-devkit/build-angular

echo "Running on port 8081"
ng serve --port 8081 --host 0.0.0.0 

echo "Done"
```

My peers are able to build an image using this code and run the container successfully. Since all the dependencies of the project are installed through docker, and since I am using the exact same codebase, I suspected that the issue had something to do with my machine.

I've tried:

1. Updating my mac to Sonoma 14.3
2. Downgrading docker to 4.19.0
3. Allocating additional RAM to Docker